# Changing Conda environments in jupyter-lab from Visual studios

Tags: python, visual-studio, jupyter, environment, jupyter-lab

In visual Studio, we can change the conda environment by going to the bottom left, clicking on your python instance, and out comes your list of python environments you can choose from and you can search for the exact `"Python 3.7.6 64-bit ("myproject":conda)` using the search bar to find keywords.

[image: search works]

However, if you're in visual studio's Jupyter-lab window, nothing you set there will effect the environment you're dealing with. The way to do it here is you go to the top right and select from a list of your environments, but this time all the names are the same so the search function doesn't work at all.

[image: No search because all the names are 'python 3']

When you have a lot of environments, search feature is something I would like to have. Is there a simpler way to either type the environment you want or to select the environment you want (with search capabilities) for jupyter-lab?

Comment: What is "visual studio's Jupyter-lab window"? Being quite familiar with JupyterLab as a standalone application, this term confuses me quite a bit.

Comment: So there's a jupyter-lab extension in Visual studios that lets you run notebooks. The interface is a little different to the jupyter-lab session running in your browser.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that extension?

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-jupyter

Comment: This has no relation to JupyterLab; there is no mention of jupyterlab in there; as these are very different things, please correct the title, tags and content to reflect that.

Comment: To expand on that vscode-jupyter is a project developed by Microsoft, while JupyterLab is an official sub-project of [Project Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/). Another issue in the tags is that you mention visual-studio, but what you use appears to be visual-studio-code. You are more likely to get an answer if you tag your questions correctly.